# Binding style values inside directive template

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-directive

I have this directive :

```
app.directive('MessageChild', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pos: '=?',
            msg: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.msg = attr.msg;
            scope.styleVar = "100"  //I want to insert this variable
        },
        template: '<style> div {position: absolute; top: **<scope variable or binding here>** }</style>' +
'<div>{{msg}}</div>'

})
```

This is just an example to show what I am trying to do.  My styles are actually substantially more complicated and involve animations.  I need to perform some operations and then pass the value to my styles.  How can I inject a variable at this location from within my directive?  Angular doesn't like me putting bindings inside styles.

Comment: Could elaborate a bit more, please, maybe I'm a lil slow. Your template syntax is also wrong.

Comment: could you add plunkr/fiddle with what you have tried

Comment: I have animation styles that I need to adjust on the fly, so I need the animation values to be variable so I can calculate and input them into the template.

Where's the syntax problem?

Comment: I'll try to get a plunker set up for playing around with...but I have tried just using bindings like {{styleVar}}.  I have trying converting it to a function and returning the template as the value of a variable and injecting scope into the template

Answer (score 0):

You could try constructing an object within the `link` function, which can then be passed into an ngStyle directive.

```
app.directive('messageChild', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pos: '=?',
            msg: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.msg = attr.msg;
            scope.styleVar = {
              'color': 'blue',
              'position': 'absolute',
              'top': '100'
            };
        },
        template: '<div ng-style="styleVar">{{msg}}</div>'
    };

});
```

**Example Plunker:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/b1uO8N

**EDIT**

You can accomplish the same using the `<style>` tag if you wish:

```
app.directive('messageChild', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pos: '=?',
            msg: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.msg = attr.msg;
            scope.styleVar = 'blue';
        },
        template: '<style> div {position: absolute; top: 100; color: {{styleVar}}}</style><div>{{msg}}</div>'
    };

});
```

**Example Plunker:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/8NxKFS?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I am aware of ng-style, but it does nothing for more complex styling, such as animations where you have to do multiple class selectors.  ng-style only applies styling directly to the element.

Comment: I am actually using it for some things and I don't like the way it applies  the styles.  Animations don't respond to it's styles the same as styles directly in the template.

Comment: ok I see what the problem was.  It didn't like me assigning a number to the bindings.  If you assign a string it works.

Comment: Assigning a number should work. For example, setting `scope.pos = 100;` inside of the `link` function sets the style correctly (see http://plnkr.co/edit/6kEoMO). Good to hear it's working now. :-)

Comment: you  might want to look at that again.  try changing the value of scope.pos.

Comment: I just have. I'm still confident that you can use numbers and not only strings. You're right though that in the Plunker I posted in my previous comment, setting `scope.pos` to a number other than 100 in the `link` function would not have changed the style. This is because the value for `pos` set here in the template was taking priority: `<message-child msg="test" pos="100"></message-child>`. Once `pos="100"` is removed from the template, changing the value of `scope.pos` has an effect. I've updated the Plunker to show what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/6kEoMO. I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I think that Andrew Sala's Answer is correct, I played around with the plunker to see if it could be "animated"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');   </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<style>
  * { transition: all 0.5s}
</style>
<script>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

var mc = this;

mc.name = 'World';
mc.msg = '!';

mc.data = { pos: 250, color: 'blue', size: 100 }; 

 $timeout(function() {
   mc.msg = "bob";
   mc.data = { pos: 240, color: 'yellow', size: 160  }; 
 }, 1500);

 $timeout(function() {
   mc.msg = "bob is";
   mc.data = { pos: 230, color: 'orange', size: 210 }; 
 }, 2500);

 $timeout(function() {
   mc.msg = "bob is COMING!";
   mc.data = { pos: 220, color: 'red' , size: 300}; 
 }, 3500);

 }]);

 app.directive('messageChild', function($timeout) {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {

        stuff: '=',
        msg: '@'
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log(scope.stuff);

        scope.styleVar = scope.stuff.color;
          scope.pos = scope.stuff.pos;

        scope.$watch('stuff', function() {
          console.log(scope.stuff);
          scope.pos = scope.stuff.pos;
          scope.styleVar = scope.stuff.color;
          scope.size = scope.stuff.size;
        })
     },
     template: '<style> div {position: absolute; top: {{pos}}px; left: 100px; font-size: {{size}}% ; color: {{styleVar}}}</style><div>{{msg}}</div>'
    };

 });
</script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
  <p>Hello {{mc.name}}!</p>
  <message-child msg="{{mc.msg}}" stuff="mc.data" >stuff</message-child>
</body>

</html>
```

[Animated Text](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFuXP9?p=preview)

You can insert the style tag for each item, or you could use ng-style, I'm assigning various "class's"  for my animations, but also have included some inline styling for 'glows' and 'blurring'